# yii2, auto function after execute like afterSave

Tags: php, yii2

I have this query, and i need afterSave for this.

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->update(User::tableName(), ['img' => 'testedimg.jpg'], ['uid' => $uid])
            ->execute();
```

how to create auto function after execute?

Comment: This should to give you an idea to execute your code after model saved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381965/yii2-how-to-resave-the-modal-in-aftersave

Comment: There is no callback or event in `yii\db\Command::excute()` method. If you really want to have it, you would have to extend the `Command` class and override its execute. You would also need to extend `yii\db\Connection` and override its `createCommand()` method to create instance of your extended `Command`. And you would need to configure app's db component to use your extended `Connection` class instead of default. But, you should probably look for another way to achieve what you are trying to do. Executing some code when any command is executed sounds suspicious.